# PGRouting create topology using a subset of a table

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I need to create a series of street networks for a neighbourhood in a city. I have used PGRouting before using a whole table to create a topology but I have not been able to do so with only a subset, as you'll see here.

I'm using the following query.

```
WITH vkk AS (SELECT name, way
            FROM planet_osm_polygon
            WHERE admin_level = '10'
            AND name = 'Vallcarca i els Penitents'),
    roads as (SELECT r.osm_id, r.way
             FROM planet_osm_line r
              JOIN vkk v
              ON ST_Contains(v.way, r.way)
             WHERE highway IS NOT NULL)
SELECT pgr_createTopology('roads', 5, 'way', 'osm_id',
 'source', 'target', rows_where := 'true')
```

This returns the following error

```
NOTICE:  PROCESSING:
NOTICE:  pgr_createTopology('roads', 5, 'way', 'osm_id', 'source', 'target', rows_where := 'true', clean := f)
NOTICE:  Performing checks, please wait .....
NOTICE:  ----> PGR ERROR in pgr_createTopology: Table roads not found
HINT:    ----> Check your table name
NOTICE:  Unexpected error raise_exception

Successfully run. Total query runtime: 47 msec.
1 rows affected.
```

Is there any solution besides creating a table for each neighbourhood I need to do this and then delete it? (I'd loop through the queries using sqlalchemy or something of the sort)

Comment: That function needs a proper relation to pull data from. You can prepare `TEMP` tables, or properly utilize the `rows_where` filter. If not already, it may be a good idea to extract the greater AOI from the OSM data, and create a seamless network topology. Then run further analysis and routing on particular neighborhoods dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

AS @geozelot writes in a comment, the `pgr_createTopology` function refers to a table name as the first argument, but in your query this table does not exist.

Instead of creating a table for each neighborhood you could create a view for each neighborhood. I made a quick test with the workshop data and PostgreSQL 13 and `pgr_createTopology` is able to populate the topology information also in a view, which eventually will not work in older versions of PostgreSQL.

Or you can use the `rows_where` argument, which allows to apply a filter query.

```sql
SELECT  pgr_createTopology('roads', 0.00001, rows_where:='id < 10');
```